# PHP long running script alternative?

Tags: php

I'm trying to download a file from a remote server with `file_put_contents`.  This script is called via ajax.  The problem i'm having is the script timeout when the file is large e.g. (500mb). I get **504 Gateway Timeout - nginx**

download.php
      $destination = "/home/mywebsite/public_html/wp-content/channels/videos/test.mp4";

```
    $link = "http://www.example.com/videos/movie.mp4"; //500mb
    $result = file_put_contents($destination, fopen($link, 'r'));
```

I'm using dedicated hosting.  I've changed my php.ini and confirmed in `phpinfo();`

`max_execution_time 7200
max_input_time  7200
max_input_vars  1000
memory_limit    -1
output_buffering    4096
post_max_size   1200M
upload_max_filesize 1000M`

This script keeps timing out.  Is there another solution how do i solve?  When i check the directory the file is successfully downloaded but the page times out.  So i can't return any data via ajax.

How do i solve?

Comment: instead i would suggest you to execute wget from php exex

Comment: If you are downloading the file on your server and it is not being served to anyone in that request there is no need for PHP to be there in the first place. You can simply do `wget http://www.example.com/videos/movie.mp4` if you have *NIX

Answer (score 1):

You should also change nginx fcgi timeout values. PHP script continues executing but your connection between nginx and PHP timeouts.

Answer (score 1):

Make download asynchronous. Like one process only fill some DB or rabbitMq with download requests and other wil cosume it (maybe cron)

Comment: This is the most sensible option for long-running processes. It's also fairly good protection against DOS attacks, as an attempt would just generate a bunch of request entries in your database (which you could easily block by putting a limit on how many entries a specific user can have at once) rather than bringing your server down by flooding it with long-running processes.

Comment: will the cron script timeout?

Comment: It may but that timeout you can override by `ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);` in php code without any changes in nginx (whitch is not maintained by you..just asuming)